# Selecting 2nd object in an array in Postman

Tags: json, object, postman

AH, a very simple question, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. This is my first set of postman tests. I have a request that returns this JSON response:

```
{
    "requestId": "3dd0#170fa14fb64",
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 52508,
            "status": "deleted"
        },
        {
            "id": 52507,
            "status": "deleted"
        }
    ],
    "success": true
```

I want to write a test that verifies that both of the status objects within the result array will have the value "deleted" but I don't know the correct syntax to do so...so far I have this

```
pm.test("Test users deleted successfully", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.result[0].status).to.eql("deleted");
    });
```

This works great for verifying the first status object, but how do I target the second one in that array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to loop through the `result` array:

```
pm.test("Test users deleted successfully", () => {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    _.each(jsonData.result, (item) => {
        pm.expect(item.status).to.eql("deleted"); 
    });
});
```

I've used the Lodash `.each()` function here, which is built-in to Postman, but you can do this with a native JS `for` loop, it works the same way I just prefer this syntax.

More info:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp